# Laravel - prevent validation check on empty inputs

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-5

there is some input fields in a form and this is my rules defined in Model :

```
  public static $rules = [
    'name' => 'string',
    'email' => 'email',
    'phone' => 'sometimes|numeric',
    'mobile' => 'numeric',
    'site_type_id' => 'integer'
];
```

none of them are required. but when form is submitted, validation errors emerged that email should be an email address and so for other inputs.
in this situation having a field `required` is meaningless as laravel always validate field against rules.
I know when form is submitted empty fields  have a `null` value.how should i prevent field validation for empty fields?

Comment: You can accept your own answer now I guess

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Laravel 5.3 onwards `nullable` can be used for optional fields:

https://laravel.com/docs/validation#rule-nullable

> you will often need to mark your "optional" request fields as nullable if you do not want the validator to consider null values as invalid

so the `rules` array should be like this:

```
public static $rules = [
    'name' => 'nullable|string',
    'email' => 'nullable|email',
    'phone' => 'nullable|numeric',
    'mobile' => 'nullable|numeric',
    'site_type_id' => 'nullable|integer'
];
```